# PHP, Zend Framework: How to fetch a page from another server, then deliver the content?

Tags: php, zend-framework, screen-scraping

I think this might also be referred to as "scraping". Basically, what I want to do, is if someone clicks this link:

```
<a href="/links/display/id/47">Click here</a>
```

I want my `links` controller, `display` action to:

1. find the actual url of link #47 from the database (i.e. http://www.google.com),
2. fetch/scrape the content,
3. display the content in the browser as if it came from my application.

I want the browser window to display `http://myapp.com/links/display/id/47` as the location in the browser window. That way, if a user (who has not been authenticated) requests to view this page, they will be sent to the login screen.

For more information on why I would want to do this, [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910745/how-to-display-a-web-page-and-keep-its-location-a-secret).

Answer (score 3):

Zend_Http_Client, send request, get response :)